# Is there any free plugin available for visual studio 2013 to debug Javascript Code?

Tags: javascript, debugging, visual-studio-2013

I want to debug javascript code similarly like C# Code is there any free plugin available for visual studio 2013 to debug Javascript Code ?

Comment: VS has inbuild Debuger for Javascript, just put break point, and attach to the process.

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1CHMD_enAU561AU561&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=visual%20studio%20debug%20javascript Seems like a good place to start...

Comment: use the `debugger;` command in your js code where you want to start debugging.

Comment: Open page in your browser, press F12, a `console` will be opened and go to `sources` tab, find your `js` file, click on line numbers, a debugger will be attached! Keep the console open and refresh the page again or just put `debugger` in js page and keep your `console` open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `debugger;` in function to debug javascript.. no need of any plugin.. 
Use `IE browser` and make `enable debugging` to debug that script.

For more reference - [How to debug the javascript in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11982564/how-to-debug-the-javascript-in-asp-net)

Comment: There is no `#debugger`. There is only `debugger;`

Comment: yes it is debugger; I was trying to highlight but it put # before that word by mistake..

Comment: Thanks will check that !